Термин для обозначения всех аспектов "правильной" письменной речи
Какое слово (термин) наиболее полно описывает "правильную" письменную речь? То есть подразумевает

Умение правильно расставлять знаки препинания

Умение правильно писать слова и разделять их пробелом/дефисом/тире (Пример 1: Москва — Петушки) или писать раздельно
Пример 2: какие либо (вместо какие-либо)
Пример 3: не сколько (вместо несколько)
Пример 4: карова

Умение наиболее уместно "соединять" ед. и множ. число
Пример: Мужчины, предупредите ваших жён, что враг уже близко!
(Этот пример прост. Да, теоретически мы конечно могли бы интерпретировать это предложение как многие из этих мужчин женаты на нескольких женщинах, но замена ваших жён на вашу жену не только не делает трактовку однозначной, но и явно режет глаз. Но часто всё не так просто.)

И вообще умение строить длинные и сложные предложения так, чтобы различных неоднозначностей и повторов в них было как можно меньше. И вообще так, чтобы они были одновременно как можно более простыми, понятными и короткими.


Интуиция подсказывает, что термины грамотность и грамотная речь не совсем точно здесь подходят.

Именно грамотная речь.
Ведь "грамотность" подразумевает не только отсутствие ошибок при письме, но и:

обладающий необходимыми знаниями, сведениями в какой-л. области;
знающий. Г. инженер. Политически грамотен. Кто-л. - г. в военном деле
человек;
выполненный со знанием дела, в соответствии с основными требованиями
данной области знаний; правильный. Г. чертёж. Сделать грамотную
разработку чего-л.

Так что грамотной речью мы назовём не только безошибочную с позиций языка, но и с красивой архитектоникой, точным дроблением на абзацы, "дышащую", наполненную "воздухом", а не неподъёмный монолит-брандмауэр без просвета для вдоха читающего.
